# PHP import existing ZIP file into database

Tags: php, oracle, zip, compression, file-get-contents

I have a PHP function for importing user selected files, mainly text and CSV, into our database. I now wish to extend its functionality to cater for a compressed ZIP folder.

At present I am using `file_get_contents` to get the file content and bind that as a CLOB in order to store into a table.

Unfortunately installing additional libraries, or similar, is not an option for me & we do not have ZipArchive available. However we do have ZIP functions such as `zip_open`, `zip_read` etc.

When I use `file_get_contents` on an existing ZIP it appears to lose or corrupt some of the data & thus cannot be uncompressed. An error 'The Compressed (zipped) Folder is invalid' on windows is given.

Having looked at other similar questions & documentation one option seems to be for me to read and extract the existing selected ZIP, loop through its contents, create a completely new compressed ZIP & then use this for binding into our database. I will likely go down this path if needs be but I am hoping someone here might be able to advise me a smarter solution using a combination of `zip_open` and `file_get_contents` etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want do divide zip to discrete files or opposite? In both cases you can consider zip processing on Oracle DB side. In depends of your Oracle version you have different options, for example [APEX_ZIP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/APEX_ZIP.html) package.

Comment: No I do not wish to divide, I wish to keep it intact as one. I need to do this on the PHP side if possible.

Comment: Probably [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) will be useful for you. And you need to store binary files in BLOB, not in CLOB.